# Array of Hashes in Hash of Hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have this HoH

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $a = {
    '0' => {
            'i' => -1,
            'u'  => -1,
    },
};
```

But what I would like is

```
my $a = {
    '0' => {
            'i' => -1,
        'u'  => -1,
            (
              {
               'i' => -1,
               't' => -1,
              },
            ),
          },
        };
```

which gives an error.

Is it not possible in have an AoH in a HoH?

Comment: Go read [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Always include the error in the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably yelling you "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at $filename line $line", right?  That's because you can't really just stuff an array into a hash by itself -- the array ref will need to be keyed, just like any other hash element.  Also, you will need to use [] instead of () to make an array ref:

```
my $a = {
    0 => {
        i => -1,
        u => -1,
        x => [{i => -1, t => -1}],
    },
};
```

produces no errors.  Then you can access into it like so: $a->{0}{x}[0]{i};

Answer (score 2):

You should have a key before your array :

```
my $a = {
    '0' => {
            'i' => -1,
            'u'  => -1,
            'a' => [
      # here ^ is the key
              {
               'i' => -1,
               't' => -1,
              },
            ],
          },
        };
```

Comment: You also changed the () around his AoH into [], which was necessary in order to create an array reference (which can be used in this way) rather than a plain list (which cannot).